# Sending data to HTTP server using socket

Tags: sockets, vb6

I'm writing a program in vb 6. I want to send data to my server and get returned data
but I faced a problem: when I send data( without any error) there is no answer from my server.
**Note**: I'm using XAMPP as server and it's ok with browser!!!

```
Private blnConnected As Boolean


Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
    Dim str As String
    str = "GET /newpass/ HTTP/1.1" & vbNewLine & "Host: localhost" & _
        vbNewLine & "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.21) Gecko/20110830 Firefox/3.6.21" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" & _
        vbNewLine & "Keep-Alive: 115" & _
        vbNewLine & "Connection: keep-alive"
    winsock.Protocol = sckTCPProtocol
    winsock.RemoteHost = "localhost"
    winsock.RemotePort = 80
    winsock.Connect
    While Not blnConnected
        DoEvents
    Wend


    winsock.SendData str

End Sub


Private Sub winsock_Connect()
 blnConnected = True
End Sub

Private Sub winsock_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
    Dim strResponse As String
    winsock.GetData strResponse, vbString, bytesTotal
    info.Text = strResponse
End Sub

Private Sub winsock_Error(ByVal Number As Integer, Description As String, ByVal Scode As Long, ByVal Source As String, ByVal HelpFile As String, ByVal HelpContext As Long, CancelDisplay As Boolean)
winsock.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.  VB6 has AsyncRead built in, Win2K and later have WinHTTP, and almost anything has MSXML so there are at least 3 ways to do this without error-prone hand coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 2 newlines after your last header. That will indicate to the server that the headers are complete.

```
str = "GET /newpass/ HTTP/1.1" & vbNewLine & "Host: localhost" & _
        vbNewLine & "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.21) Gecko/20110830 Firefox/3.6.21" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" & _
        vbNewLine & "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" & _
        vbNewLine & "Keep-Alive: 115" & _
        vbNewLine & "Connection: keep-alive" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```

Comment: Thanks. Such a rookie mistake :-D

Comment: Note that WinInet abstarcts almost all of this away and supports many "variations" on the standard that are in use.

Comment: True: WinInet supports HTTP directly, so one would be able to directly use that instead of *bit-banging* the network data, but if this is the desired path, we're here for you :)